# How can I call another Java Script function if I confirm Yes on window.onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I call another Java Script function if I confirm Yes on below window.onbeforeunload event.

```
function closeIt() {
return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure you want to exit";
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call another Java Script function if I confirm Yes on below window.onbeforeunload event.

If by "yes" you mean "Yes, leave" then you might be able to use the `unload` event on `window`. Note that you can't do much of anything at that point.

If by "yes" you mean "Yes, stay on the page" then you can do that just by setting a timed callback with `setTimeout`.

Here's a complete example which records to local storage whether you left or stayed (tested on Firefox, Chrome, and IE11):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Closing</title>
<style>
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
(function() {
    display("foo = " + (localStorage.getItem("foo") || "<em>not set</em>"));

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            localStorage.setItem("foo", "stayed at " + new Date());
            display("Stayed");
        }, 10);
        return "Really leave?";

    };
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("unload", left, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onunload", left);
    } else {
        window.onunload = left;
    }

    function left() {
        localStorage.setItem("foo", "left at " + new Date());
    }

    function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the function

```
confirm(message)
```

Depending on what you click ("Ok" or "Cancel"), it returns a boolean value. After testing for this return value, you can take an action you want.

```
if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    alert("Yes, you are!")};
} else {
    alert("Why not?")
}
```